# Chromium Build 18 always gets FileReader NOT_READABLE_ERR

Tags: c#, javascript, chromium, filereader

I'm running a C# application.  This C# application embeds a Chromium (build 18) browser, which points to a remote site running on http.  It's a Backbone/Require site, so it's 99% JavaScript.

Everything on this site works exactly the same as it does inside of Chrome, with the exception of the FileReader.  No matter what we try to upload, we arrive at NOT_READABLE_ERR.

I'm aware of the build 14 bug which would always trigger NOT_READABLE_ERR.  That has been corrected in build 18 (allegedly?).

I've also tried enabling the --file-allow-file-access flag.  That did not help.

The related JS code is as follows.  Sorry, I don't have access to the C# code but if there are any pitfalls I may be falling in to I can make a recommendation for a change there.  I suspect the C# is OK, because http://www.google.com/imghp works OK inside of our embedded Chromium browser.

Some notes:
The files are not locked.
We have tried multiple files and file types.
The C# application runs locally (windows client) and embeds a Chromium browser directed to an http site.

```
// called from <input type='file'> change event
fileSelected: function(e) {
    this._processFile(e.target.files[0]);
},

_processFile: function(filehandle) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(evt) {
        console.log('done loading', evt);
    };

    reader.onprogress = function(evt) {
        console.log("on progress!");
        if(evt.lengthComputable) {
            console.log("loaded: " + evt.loaded);
            console.log("total: " + evt.total);
        }
    };

    reader.onloadstart = function(evt) {
        console.log("on load start!");
    };

    reader.onerror = function(evt) {
        switch(evt.target.error.code) {
            case evt.target.error.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
                console.log('File Not Found!');
                break;
            case evt.target.error.NOT_READABLE_ERR:  // we always arrive here, no matter what type of file.  img, pdf, etc.  files are not locked.
                console.log('File is not readable');
                break;
            case evt.target.error.ABORT_ERR:
                break; // noop
            default:
                console.log('An error occurred reading this file.');
        };
    };

    reader.onabort = function() {
        console.log("upload aborted.");
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(filehandle);
}
```